# Using opensource libraries to get generator of a finite cylic group (Diffie Hellman)

Tags: openssl, cryptography, diffie-hellman

Which open source libraries is able to generate the following

1. `G` a finite cylic group of prime order `q`
2. `g` a generator in `G`

where the decisional diffie-hellman problem is intractable

3. generate a random number `x \in G`

I’m currently looking into openssl, but im not sure if `openssl dhparam` is the right fit

Answer (score 0):

The [pyca/cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) could be useful for you.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dh
parameters = dh.generate_parameters(generator=2, key_size=2048)
parameters.parameter_numbers().p
parameters.parameter_numbers().g
parameters.generate_private_key().private_numbers().x
```

Note that in general it is not advised to generate your own Diffie-Hellman parameters but rather use the  specification for reasons outlined in [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29926/what-diffie-hellman-parameters-should-i-use).